# Can’t connect my iPad to cPanel WebDisk (iOS)

Tags: webserver, ios

I am trying to connect my iPad to my webdisk, but I can’t.
I have:

- my address: example.com
- my username: exemple@exemple.com
- my password: example

I figured out to connect my Windows 10 laptop, but I don’t know how (and I found nothing on Google) to connect my iPad (maybe using files app?) to the WebDisk...

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://blog.dathorn.com/2017/08/web-disk-for-ios/) that was posted in 2017. It has mentioned about an application on the App Store. You have to install the app on your iPad and then connect with your cPanel WebDisk that you have set up.

> I am trying to connect my iPad to my webdisk, but I can’t. I have:
>
> - my address: example.com
> - my username: exemple@exemple.com
> - my password: example